Reed-Solomon correction with a stream of bits
This works with the reedsolo package:
from reedsolo import RSCodec, ReedSolomonError
rsc = RSCodec(10)  # 10 ecc symbols
rsc.encode(b'hello world')  # b'hello world\xed%T\xc4\xfd\xfd\x89\xf3\xa8\xaa'
rsc.decode(b'heXlo worXd\xed%T\xc4\xfdX\x89\xf3\xa8\xaa')[0]     # 3 errors, output: b'hello world'

but I notice that correction bytes are added at the end.
How to deal work with a stream of bytes of unknown-in-advance length, should we split the input in chunks?
Also can reedsolo work with a stream of bits? Example:
rsc.encode_bits([1, 0, 0, 1, 1])
# [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]


It would be easier to understand by showing all 10 parities as hex bytes:
rsc.encode(b'hello world')  # b'hello world\xed\x25\x54\xc4\xfd\xfd\x89\xf3\xa8\xaa'

Encoding can be done on the fly, but syndrome generation and correction requires all of the received message. Syndrome generation can be implemented on the fly by re-encoding the data, and then using matrix multiplication to convert parities into syndromes (this works because parities and syndromes are both linear mappings of the data bytes), but that Reed-Solomon library isn't going to include this, and error correction requires the entire received message.
Since this Reed-Solomon library is working with bytes, the maximum encoded message size is 255 bytes: for 10 bytes of parity, then 245 bytes data, 10 bytes parity. This assumes that 10 bytes provides enough error detection and correction for a 255 byte message based on expected error rate. It may be better to choose a smaller chunk size, like total size = 64 bytes or 128 bytes.
A stream of bits would need to be converted into a stream of bytes.
